# Flux: how to deal with objects that generate other dependent objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

**Context**: we are building a complex 3D "Sims-like" web app with React/Alt.js. Users can add simple objects in the 3D scene (a cube), but more often they will add what we call a "prefab", which is an assembly of several simple objects (15 cubes make a structure) based on some user's params (length, height, ...).

So we have an ObjectStore, with all simple objects, and PrefabStore (which only hold user's params to generate the prefab).

We could generate this prefab and its objects only in the React layer (this way the prefab render is always in sync with the prefab's params in the store), but for technical reasons we need all these prefab's simple objects to really exist in the store layer. In other words, we need to generate the prefab's objects in the store (ObjectStore since it's where simple objects are stored).

**The question is**: *where* (in the store layer), *when* and *how* to generate the prefab and all its dependent objects, and where should we store generated objects, knowing that:

1. When prefab's params are updated, we need to re-generate and update objects (existing objects could be moved, rotated, completly removed).
2. We can't compute prefab's generated objects in the React view layer since wee need these generated objects in the store layer (because these objects could interact with others, we also need them when we generate a file with all existing objects).
3. Generate a prefab and its dependent objects is a complex and slow task: we can't call this generate function each time we need to render the prefab. Furthermore, as i aid in the previous point, we need a reference to generated objects so they have to exist in the store.

To help understand what is a *prefab* and a simple *object*, and why wee need the prefab's objects to exists in the store layer, here is a screenshot of our app:
[image]

**My solutions**:

1. Generate prefab and dependent objects in a React component, on-the-fly.

**Pros**: prefab render and dependents objects are always in sync with prefab's data. When prefab's params are updated, React automagically render prefab and generate objects again.

**Cons**: objects don't really exist. They are not in ObjectStore so I can't interact with them (display object list, generate a file with all objects, ...).

2. Generate prefab and dependent objects *once* in action, then populate dependent stores (ObjectStore, PrefabStore) with generated objects.

**Pros**: all objects are stored in their own Store.

**Cons**: when you update a prefab (move/rotate/resize), it's difficult to update all dependent generated objects and you need a bunch of store lsitener in ObjectStore to ensure objects are in sync with the prefab they belong to.

3. Generate prefab and dependent objects on-the-fly, but in the store with memoization.
   **Pros**: dependent objects are always in sync + objects really exists in the store layer (not sure how to handle this memoization in two different stores: PrefabStore and ObjectStore).

**Cons**: I don't know how to handle the memoization in two different stores: PrefabStore for the prefab object (which still has position/rotation properties) and ObjectStore for generated objects.

Comment: I'm not sure of your implementation of flux, but if you're using Redux (and even if you aren't), [Reselect's memoized selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) are a common pattern for handling computed data efficiently (specifically in answer to point 3). Wherever you need a reference to the object you can `import` the selector. This keeps your state simple and optimizes calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to answer these kinds of architectural questions - you are the expert on your own system and domain, but here goes anyway:

The basic flux rule is that a Store is responsible for mutating its own state in response to an Action. Additionally, there are good general code organisation practices, such as having low coupling and high cohesion, etc.

One option would be:

1. Some kind of Prefab model object, that knows about the parameters of
   a single prefab 'template' and has a generate method to create and return the
   appropriate Objects (perhaps the generate method has to take some position info or something as params). The prefab model can decoupled from any stores, in a separate code module. The generate method can be a pure function, in its own module, if you like.
2. The Prefab Store can directly store prefab models (simplest probably), or just the data needed to construct them.
3. The Object Store has a handler for the ADD_FROM_PREFAB Action that queries the Prefab store for the appropriate Prefab model data/instance, calls
   generate on it and finally adds the returned objects into its state.
4. UI then just renders the scene from the ObjectStore, not the prefab store (though presumably the Prefab store is used for a prefab library UI as well?)

With this approach you can unit test the prefab model and object generation in isolation, and re-use it where you want easily. The store code is also fairly simple glue that's easy to test. And the UI doesn't need to worry about prefabs in the rendering part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i'm using this option right now (well, almost the same, see solution 2) in my original post): I have a prefab model which generate all dependent objects, then all dependent stores (ObjectStore) listen to "PREFAB_GENERATED" action, fetch generated objects and put them in their own store.

I'm not happy with this solution because when I update my prefab (params, position, ...), I need to update all dependent objects (move/resize/REMOVE completly), aka re-generate my prefab. How to be sure that objects are always in sync with prefab params ?

Comment: One option is to keep an index of prefab->generated objects in the ObjectStore. Then you can listen to the relevant actions relating to updates to a prefab in the ObjectStore, and you have the option of in-place updating the objects based on the change rather than re-generating them, which could have a major performance benefit. Code to handle this could be in the prefab module (e.g. it takes the array of objects and returns the updated array, potentially updating in-place).

Comment: For the memoization alternative, since you're presumably not using immutable state, you could store in the ObjectStore references to the pre-fabs only. When the view queries the object store for the pre-fabs, at that point the object store generates the objects, and caches them along with the pre-fab as it was then (I guess you'd need to copy it if it's mutable). If it has a cached list of objects with an equal prefab, you can just re-use it, otherwise replace it with a regenerated list. No need to fire anything to say your object store updated, since this is just caching, not state changes.